# prompt loops while not in a loop

Tags: jquery

I've recently started learning jQuery and just messing around with I decided to make an RTE however, I noticed when I went to enter a hyperlink, it prompts several times after a hyperlink has already been inserted, and seems to increment for every time you click the hyperlink button.

```
    $('#hyperlink').mouseover(function(){
        $('#hyperlink').css('color','#000000')
        $('#hyperlink').mouseout(function(){
            $('#hyperlink').css('color','#999999')
        });
        $('#hyperlink').click(function(){
            var url;
            url = prompt('Enter the URL you wish to link:','http://');
            $('#contentArea').focus()
            if(url != '' && url != null){
                $('#contentArea').append('<a href=\"' + url + '\">' + url + '</a>')
            }
        });
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vMFb9/

Comment: ok. (or were you about to ask us a question?)

Comment: unbind events or put outside handler function scope if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull your click event out from within the mouseover like:

```
    $('#hyperlink').mouseover(function () {
        $('#hyperlink').css('color', '#000000')
        $('#hyperlink').mouseout(function () {
            $('#hyperlink').css('color', '#999999')
        });
    });
    $('#hyperlink').click(function () {
        var url;
        url = prompt('Enter the URL you wish to link:', 'http://');
        $('#contentArea').focus()
        if (url != '' && url != null) {
            $('#contentArea').append('<a href=\"' + url + '\">' + url + '</a>')
        }
    });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vMFb9/1/)**

It's being triggered multiple times because of where in the code you put the click event.

Comment: Should the mouseout eventhandler be nested within the mouseover?  Would that create the same issue with just a less noticeable effect?

Comment: @KevinBowersox - no, probably not (although it doesn't seem to be causing any issues).

Comment: @j08691 Not trying to bash any answers just wanted to point that out.  Good job solving the main issue +1

Answer (score 4):

You're adding the click handler *inside* the mouseover handler.

Every time the mouse moves into the element (or its descendents), you're adding another click handler.
When you click it, all of those handlers run in sequentially.

That's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not nest mouseout or `click` inside of mouseover
2. You should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`
3. You can use `.on()` to combine them all into one!

   ```
   $('#hyperlink').on({
       mouseenter:function(){
           $(this).css('color','#000000');
       },
       mouseleave:function(){
           $(this).css('color','#999999');
       },
       click:function(){
           var url = prompt('Enter the URL you wish to link:','http://'),
               $contentArea = $('#contentArea');

           $contentArea.focus();
           if(!isEmpty(url)){
               $contentArea.append('<a href=\"' + url + '\">' + url + '</a>');
           }
       }
   });

   function isEmpty(str) {
       return (!str || 0 === str.length);
   }
   ```

That should do it! The reason for combining them into a single `.on()` binding is because the DOM doesn't need to be scraped each time for the manipulation. Now the item only needs to be found once and can have all events bound to it. This is the fastest way to perform the intended manipulation.

**EDIT**: Updated with a cool function to check if string is empty.

Comment: Haha sadly by putting so much effort into this answer, I was too late to get any recognition.

Comment: no worries. i also updated it to make better use of `$(this)` and turning `$('#contentArea')` into a variable. Whenever you use an object more than once, always cache it in a variable, and when referencing the item in its own function use `$(this)` instead of calling it again. Each time that object is called by name rather than cache, the DOM is scraped, so reducing the number of scrapes means faster runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta keep'em separated!  The eventhandlers that is.  The `mouseover` event handler is attaching a new handler to the hyperlink each time it is moused over.

```
$('#hyperlink').mouseover(function(){
    $('#hyperlink').css('color','#000000')
});

$('#hyperlink').mouseout(function(){
        $('#hyperlink').css('color','#999999')
});

$('#hyperlink').click(function(){
    var url;
    url = prompt('Enter the URL you wish to link:','http://');
    $('#contentArea').focus()

    if(url != '' && url != null){
        $('#contentArea').append('<a href=\"' + url + '\">' + url + '</a>')
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Works too but should not be used, at least give you the idea why it wasn't working:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vMFb9/2/)

```
$('#hyperlink').mouseover(function(){
                $('#hyperlink').css('color','#000000')
                $('#hyperlink').off('mouseout').mouseout(function(){
                    $('#hyperlink').css('color','#999999')
                });
                $('#hyperlink').off('click').click(function(){
                    var url;
                    url = prompt('Enter the URL you wish to link:','http://');
                    $('#contentArea').focus()
                    if(url != '' && url != null){
                        $('#contentArea').append('<a href=\"' + url + '\">' + url + '</a>')
                    }
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate

```
$('#hyperlink').click(function(){});
```

from mouseover function